# how to include local parameters in the function defined in a interface and call them

Tags: typescript, interface

**Problem:**
*Create an interface Personnel, with the fields as ID, name and salary. Also, declare a function displayDetails() to display the ID, name and salary on the console.
Create Trainee class that strictly implements Personnel interface. Apart from interface properties and methods, it should also have CGPA and classroom as properties.
Create one object of Trainee class with the values as given below
Invoke displayDetails() method on created object to display all the available details.*

Interface personal has a displayDetails method which i need to define in the Trainee class and call the function using the object of the class. But when i call, it gives me an error, as the parameters don't match as i have local parameters in the trainee class which i need to include in the function i.e. if i call displayDetails function i can pass only 3 parameters, but i also need to include the 2 local parameters in the function. How do i achieve it? how do i include the local parameters in the displayDetails function along with the interface parameters? below is the code and hope my question is clear

```
interface Personal{
    id:number;
    name:string;
    salary:number;
    displayDetails(id:number, name:string, salary:number);
}
class Trainee implements Personal{
    id:number;
    name:string;
    salary:number;
    cgpa:number;
    classroom:string;
    displayDetails(id:number, name:string, salary:number, cgpa:number, classroom:string){
        console.log(id, name, salary, );
    }
}
var trainee=new Trainee();
trainee.displayDetails(101,"John", 2000, 9.2, "G-063");
```

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), preferably in `--strict` mode.  Right now that code has some errors in it unrelated to the one you're talking about.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to accomplish.  By saying `Trainee implements Personal`, you're claiming that I can use a `Trainee` the same way I use a `Personal`: `const p: Personal = new Trainee()`;  Specifically, I should be able to call `p.displayDetails(1,"",1)`.  But `Trainee`'s `displayDetails()` method expects 5 parameters, not 3.  So a `Trainee()` is *not* a `Personal`.  Why do you need `Personal` at all?  Can you show a use case where you need `Personal` to exist?

Comment: Why is [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECiC2AHEB7AngUw9A3gWAChpjoBLAEwC5oA7AV3gCMMAnaAXmgAYBuQk2mHgZqEAC4tSNAOYdoAInl8iJCGHAs01ek1Zze-EohYoAVhmBjREqbM6LlA1MDBjSKGtcky5Dw8XJSCGQwNAARDDEwUhAIAAoKbQZmFgAaQWEvW3S1DS1aZNZ04zMLK2hxb2l051d3TwqbGQBKXH8BaGAPCBQQDAA6VGkE8nSaIQwc9TBNZscSAF9CJYJQSBgAFRZomiw2lWJEgt02TgMDjJFGqt8ldtyZ-J0UuQBGeeJgaUQwJJO5ABMH064CgJhQ8CyPnsdwugWC4HCkWisRGfxSYwmUOqFWmmnRRU631+xwxIPW4Mh11srXwFwEXRoPT6gxQwwomOEUzyqTm7RWKwAbjNoBIdntOLsAO7QLbijBxPkEMVSLD9eEhJFRGLxV7pRTpAHpADM+vkSuFbAwSFQmGwkowMoQyHQWEVymtLrt6qCmoi2tReoU8nSQYNwda0CAA) not enough?

Comment: I am new to typescript, i was going through a course and when i approached the "Interface" topic it gave me a problem to solve. So using an interface is necessary. I have edited the code to include the original problem and also trimmed the code down keeping only the necessary for better understanding and clarity. I saw your code there was no interface used.